# Difference between Nant / CruiseControl/Teamcity

Tags: rake, teamcity, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have spent a couple of days going through a lot of sites and reading about Nant , Rake etc.

please forgive my Noob question but I still cannot find what is the difference between Nant and CruiseControl.
As far as I can see Nant can do automated builds , run tests .
so what extra does cruisecontrol do ?

Also there was mention of Teamcity . there too from the documents I can see it can do builds but it also can use Nant but I fail to understand why it needs to use Nant when it can do the builds itself

I am basically trying to follow proper software practices by introducing automated builds at my workplace

Appreciate all  help

Answer (score 10):

Nant by itself can do builds and test, but it needs to be launched by some other mechanism such as a windows scheduled job.  There is not a capability of launching the build only when source code changes, at least without 
an amount of additional scripting.

Nant itself is just a script runner, not a scheduler - it requires some other software (or a manual user action) to launch it.

Continuous integration (CI)  tools such as CruiseControl or TeamCity provide monitoring of source control to launch a build process in addition to other things. The build itself could the be a single nant script which runs the build and tests as you suggest, or the build could be done using a series of tasks which are built in to the CI server.  The difference is not how the builds are done, but how they are initiated and reported.

CI servers additionally usually provide web-based reporting of the details of the build runs and unit tests.

In summary, Ci tools provide monitoring, scheduling, and reportingin addition to scripting of the build process.

Comment: Thank you very much Thierry for your detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

Nant is a scripting language
CruiseControl is a free continuse integration tools
Teamcity in another contiuse integration tools,

regards,